Get push clicks in new Flutter huawei_push plugin version
Using the example from huawei_push, I failed to get push clicks on remote (downlink) notifications.
I've seen this question. However, it does not work for me because:

I cannot use intents (we share deeplink format with iOS and other push providers on Android.)
Answer is outdated and since then huawei_push has that functionality built-in

Downlink messages sent from REST api (and other ways) are successfully received, but push clicks are not registered.
From local push notifications from example however push clicks are correctly registered.
My goal is to get the data parameter from the notification payload from remote messages (example I tried below)
{
   "message":{
      "data":"{'deepLink': 'https://google.com'}",
      "token":[
         "<my token was here>"
      ],
      "android":{
         "notification":{
            "title":"Some test title",
            "body":"Some test body",
            "click_action": {
                "type": 3
            },
           "foreground_show": false
         }
      }
   }
}

Device: huawei p8 lite, with huawei services installed separately

Tried changing foreground_show parameter (did not see any difference in behavior)

